# Python: How to call a method from another module?

Tags: python, module

I have 2 files written in python. main.py looks like this:

```
import cats

class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):
        print("My name is "+self.name)

dog = Dog("Boxer")
cats.cat.talk()
```

and cats.py that looks like this:

```
class Cat():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):
        print("my name is "+self.name)
    def MakeDogTalk(self):
        dog.talk()
cat = Cat("pus")
cat.MakeDogTalk()
```

as you can see, i am trying to make the dog talk from the cats module, is there some way to make this work? My real world app looks nothing like this btw...
of course,now i get this error:

```
line 9, in MakeDogTalk 
dog.talk()
NameError: name 'dog' is not defined
```

Comment: also, i run the main.py file...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, you should try to minimize the amount of file-level code in a module. In other words, if you intend to import a file, the executable code in that file should be inside a function or class when possible. `cat = Cat("pus")` and `cat.MakeDogTalk()` aren't inside a function or class, so I'd move them to `main.py`.

`dog` isn't going to be visible inside `MakeDogTalk`, so I would pass `dog` as a parameter to either the Cat constructor, or the MakeDogTalk method.

Approach 1: passing the parameter into the constructor

```
import cats
#main.py
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):
        print("My name is "+self.name)

dog = Dog("Boxer")
cat = cats.Cat("pus", dog)
cat.MakeDogTalk()
cat.talk()

#cats.py
class Cat():
    def __init__(self, name, dog):
        self.name = name
        self.dog = dog
    def talk(self):
        print("my name is "+self.name)
    def MakeDogTalk(self):
        self.dog.talk()
```

Approach 2: passing the parameter into the method

```
import cats

class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):
        print("My name is "+self.name)

dog = Dog("Boxer")
cat = cats.Cat("pus")
cat.MakeDogTalk(dog)
cat.talk()

#cats.py
class Cat():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):
        print("my name is "+self.name)
    def MakeDogTalk(self, dog):
        dog.talk()
```

It would also be simple to keep all of your dog-based logic exclusive to main.py:

```
#main.py
import cats

class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):
        print("My name is "+self.name)

dog = Dog("Boxer")
cat = cats.Cat("pus")
dog.talk()
cat.talk()

#cats.py
class Cat():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):
        print("my name is "+self.name)
```

... But I assume you have a good reason in your real code to have the Cat handle it.

---

If it's really absolutely necessary to keep `cat = Cat("pus")` inside `cats.py`, then you'll have to put it inside a function. If it stays at the file-level scope, then `MakeDogTalk` will execute before `import cats` finishes executing, which occurs before the `Dog` class even exists, so that's a no-go. This adds a small complication that `cats.cat` will no longer be accessible from main.py, but you can still retrieve the object by returning it from the function call.

```
#main.py
import cats

class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):
        print("My name is "+self.name)

dog = Dog("Boxer")
cat = cats.do_cat_thing(dog)
cat.talk()

#cats.py
class Cat():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):
        print("my name is "+self.name)
    def MakeDogTalk(self, dog):
        dog.talk()

def do_cat_thing(dog):
    cat = Cat("pus")
    cat.MakeDogTalk(dog)
    return cat
```

---

It may also make sense to put the `Dog` class in its own file, too. Since the Cat class depends on the Dog class, the cats file should import the dogs file. This way, you can keep your `cat = Cat("pus")` in cats.py and at the file-level scope, if that's necessary for some reason.

```
#main.py
import cats

cats.cat.talk()

#cats.py
import dogs

class Cat():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):
        print("my name is "+self.name)
    def MakeDogTalk(self):
        dogs.dog.talk()

cat = Cat("pus")
cat.MakeDogTalk()


#dogs.py
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):
        print("My name is "+self.name)

dog = Dog("Boxer")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing dog in MakeDogTalk, but it doesnt know what it is. Add this to your MakeDogTalk:

```
    def MakeDogTalk(self):
        from main import dog
        dog.talk()
```

Comment: This works, but when possible I'd advise against using circular imports (file A importing file B, which imports from file A). Python does a good job of resolving imports of this kind, but its behavior can be unintuitive to those unfamiliar with the module caching logic. And it leads to designs that might not work with languages that have less intelligent import logic, such as C++. (Not that writing language-agnostic code is necessarily hugely important; but all other things being equal, you may as well choose the solution that's easier to port)

Comment: I agree with you, it is not particularly good to do so, but I tried to give an answer that works for what he wants, and also, I only imported from the specific method, not the file scope! But you are right!